# Decussation of Cranial Nerves

Tags: neuroscience, vision, neural-network, brain, neuroanatomy

Which cranial nerves decussate apart from the few nerve fibers of the optic nerve that do and how to easilly remember the cranial nerves that do?

[Here is a paper for the Trochlear Nerve](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK537244/)

But I have found no paper for all 12 of the Cranial Nerves.

It is easier to remember the exceptions.

That way if there are fewer nerves that have some fibers decussate they should be the exception to the general rule that cranial nerves do not deccusate as they are fewer and easier to remember.

Otherwise the general rule is that even they generally decussate and the exception are those that do not have any fibers decussate.

Regardless of which is the exception a mnemonic for the exceptions would be really useful.

Comment: Does the paper about the Trochlear Nerve state it decussates, or not? Perhaps quote the exact phrasing as well to cover any potentially relevant qualifiers.

Comment: @StevenJeuris  The left and right nerves then travel dorsally surrounded by the periaqueductal gray matter, decussating before their exit in the dorsal midbrain. This paper states the Trochlear Nerve does in fact deccusate. But I have found no paper on all 12 of them. I read textbooks but in fact prefer lectures. I need some mnemonic.